# Dynamic Apex to retrieve Picklist Values for Price Book

Tags: apex

I have the following code, but its not working . I am not sure if its correct to query all the values in the PriceBook as a pick list . it doesnt understand what product2 is

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult =  Pricebook2.Name.getDescribe();
     List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
  public List<SelectOption> getPriceBook()
{
  List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

   Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult =
 Pricebook2.Name.getDescribe();
   List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

   for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
   {
      options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
   }       
   return options;
}
```

Apex

```
<apex:form>
<apex:selectList id="priceBook" value="{!Pricebook2.Name}"
         size="1" required="true">
  <apex:selectOptions value="{!priceBook}"/>
</apex:selectList>
</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of available Pricebooks is obtained from the database, not from Metadata (Describe)

So, your getter that provides all possible custom pricebooks should be:

```
public SelectOption[] availPriceBooks {
  get {if (this.availPricebooks == null) {
        this.availPricebooks = new List<SelectOption> ();
        for (Pricebook2 pb : [select id, name from Pricebook
                               where isActive = true and isStandard = false])
          this.availPriceBooks.add(new SelectOption(pb.id,pb.name));
        }
        return this.availPricebooks;
       }
  private set;
 }

public String selectedPriceBook {get; set;}
```

and your VF would look like

```
<apex:form>
  <apex:selectList id="priceBookSL" value="{!selectedPriceBook}"
                   size="1" required="true">
     <apex:selectOptions value="{!availPricebooks}"/>
  </apex:selectList>
 </apex:form>
```

*If your code creates new pricebooks, be sure to null out this.availPriceBooks before refreshing the form so the latest (added) pricebook appears in the picklist. If you are not creating new pricebooks in this VF controller, ignore this paragraph.*

And a +1 from me for not dumping unnecessary/irrelevant code into your question